# How can I print just a countries or capitals to screen using the argument 'countries' or 'capitals' using BASH script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a .txt file of the countries and their capitals in the following format,

1. Germany  Berlin
2. Belgium Brussels
3. USA     WashingtonDC
4. England London
5. Japan       Tokyo
6. Poland      Warsaw
7. Canada      Ottawa

Comment: Um, Toronto is not the [capital of Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Capital_of_Canada)

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, just insert the text itself into the question.

Comment: That was a mistake, Thanks

Comment: What separates the columns? is it space characters or tab characters? What do you do when the country contains multiple words (South Africa)?

Comment: @glennjackman They are separated by a tab character. And let's count South Africa as South.Africa like a one word.

Comment: If you use tabs, there's no need to substitute the space character.

Answer (score 1):

With shell functions:

```sh
countries () { awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' /path/to/file.txt; }
capitals  () { awk -F '\t' '{print $2}' /path/to/file.txt; }
```

You can use aliases, but the quoting gets complicated.